# tabela com campo calculado

Tags: mysql

Tabela já existente

```
CREATE TABLE `dataleitura` (
    `idLeitura` INT(6) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `DataLeitura` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idLeitura`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=11
```

---

**dados:**

```
"000001"    "2020-01-13"
"000002"    "2020-02-11"
"000003"    "2020-03-13"
"000004"    "2020-04-14"
"000005"    "2020-05-13"
"000006"    "2020-06-12"
"000007"    "2020-07-10"
"000008"    "2020-08-12"
"000009"    "2020-09-11"
"000010"    "2020-10-13"
```

Necessito criar uma coluna calculada me dando os dias entre uma data e outra
`"2020-10-13" - "2020-09-11"`

```
CREATE TABLE `dataleitura` (
    `idLeitura` INT(6) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `DataLeitura` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `dias` [GENERATED ALWAYS] AS expressão [VIRTUAL | STORED] constraints
    PRIMARY KEY (`idLeitura`)
```

como seria a expressão, alguém pode me ajudar

Comment: Não é mais fácil você criar um trigger que após algum dado ser inserido se essa coluna for nula você realiza o calculo?

Comment: poderia me explicar como faria isso, sou novato e nunca usei trigger

Answer (score 0):

Eu recomendo a utilização de um **Trigger** que ao inserir qualquer novo campo, ou atualizar algum dado o banco automaticamente calcula ou recalcula o dado dessa coluna:

```
--A trigger irá executar toda vez que um novo dado for inserido INSERT;
--É necessário ter a coluna dias já criada no código;
--SYSDATE é data atual que eu utilizei de exemplo;
--Cuidado para não confundir nome de coluna com a da tabela, no caso eu trocaria o nome da coluna.

CREATE TRIGGER trg_atualiza_dia AFTER INSERT
ON dataleitura
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE dataleitura SET dias = SYSDATE - DataLeitura
WHERE idLeitura= NEW.idLeitura;
END
```

É possível criar outra **Trigger** para **AFTER UPDATE**, caso você irá utilizar o comando de **UPDATE** (atualização) nessa tabela.

Comment: na realidade seria ultimo registro - registro anterior 
como faço isso?

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta, você precisa adaptar para as funcionalidades do seu sistema

Comment: sim, so que estou agarrado nessa de pegar a ultima data e subtrair a data anterior e saber quantos dias

Comment: Você precisa de duas datas, a data que a pessoa pegou o livro e a data que ela devolveu ai voce faz uma coluna menos a outra, voce precisa de 3 colunas